# Find overlap between two tables by multiple columns and substring

Tags: unix, awk, terminal

I want to get the overlap between two tables based on three columns.

File 1

```
 Chr        B      C       Start  End   F   G   E    D   
chr1    HAVANA  gene    11869   14409   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2";
chr1    HAVANA  gene    100000  112000  .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2";
chr3    HAVANA  gene    11870   14409   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2";
chr3    HAVANA  gene    11839   11869   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2";
chr2    HAVANA  gene    11869   14409   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2";
```

....

File 2

```
 A                       B           Start  End    Chr          D  
ENSG00000177697     ENST00000525333 832986  833026  11          1
ENSG00000197283     ENST00000876382 100000  112000  1           1
ENSG00000194582     ENST00000184632 11869   14409   2           1
ENSG00000174528     ENST00000241053 154728  184728  12          1
ENSG00000103629     ENST00000816493 832986  917483  13          1 
ENSG00000183628     ENST00000816472 711633  782163  11          1
ENSG00000192748     ENST00000164924 832986  982732  CHK_1231    1
ENSG00000183643     ENST00000917473 183728  194873  3           1
ENSG00000183647     ENST00000184637 800000  819483  2           1
ENSG00000177697     ENST00000184627 100023  120000  11          1
```

Desired output:

```
Chr        B      C       Start  End   F   G   E    D   
chr1    HAVANA  gene    100000  112000  .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2";
chr2    HAVANA  gene    11869   14409   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2";
```

The problem is that the number in file 2 in the 5th column is a substring of column 1 of the first file (So instead of 11 it would say chr11). The 4th and 5th column of table 2 should be equal to column 4 and 5 in file 1 (Start and End). I want the output exactly to look like file 1, just the elements should be equal to those in file 2.

I am not familiar with awk syntax and for me it is not intuitive, but I found while scanning through previous posts this line, I guess one could expand this command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next}{ print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1 > file1_subset2
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include more sample input (lines that do and don't match) plus the expected output given that input.

Comment: *The problem is that the number in file 2 in the 5th column is a substring of column 1 of the first file (So instead of 11 it would say chr11).* This is very confusing. `11` is not a substring of `chr1`. What does *"it would say"* refer to? Are you using *table* and *file* interchangeably in your question? What do you mean columns *"should be equal"*?

Answer (score 0):

@ELHL: Try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{sub(/[[:alpha:]]+/,"",$1);A[$1,$4,$5]=$0;next} {sub(/[[:alpha:]]+/,"",$(NF-1));} ((($NF-1),$3,$4) in A){print A[($NF-1),$3,$4]}'   SUBSEP=,   Input_file1  Input_file2
```

It will print file1's value if both have matches as per your request, kindly try and let me know then.

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
                sub(/[[:alpha:]]+/,"",$1);
                A[$1,$4,$5]=$0;
                next
            }
            {
                sub(/[[:alpha:]]+/,"",$(NF-1));
            }
     ((($NF-1),$3,$4) in A){
                                print A[($NF-1),$3,$4]
                           }
    '  SUBSEP=,    Input_file1  Input_file2
```

**EDIT2:** Adding a function where I could remove 2 times writing of sub which is doing same operation in different fields actually.

```
awk 'function remove_chars(a){sub(/[[:alpha:]]+/,"",$a)} FNR==NR{remove_chars($1);A[$1,$4,$5]=$0;next} {remove_chars($(NF-1));} ((($NF-1),$3,$4) in A){print A[($NF-1),$3,$4]}'  SUBSEP=, Input_file1   Input_file2
```

NON-one liner form of solution too as follows.

```
awk 'function remove_chars(a){
                                sub(/[[:alpha:]]+/,"",$a)
                             }
     FNR==NR                 {
                                remove_chars($1);
                                A[$1,$4,$5]=$0;
                                next
                             }
                             {
                                remove_chars($(NF-1));
                             }
     ((($NF-1),$3,$4) in A)  {
                                print A[($NF-1),$3,$4]
                             }
   ' SUBSEP=,   Input_file1   Input_file2
```